# How to line up images in a horizontal row with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line up these image links in a row but having some difficulty with it. If I add some CSS parameters like float left and float right, it ends up positioning it in weird spots on the page.

This is what I got:

```css
.preview {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.preview img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.preview > div {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 0;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
.preview:hover > div {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.preview > div div {
    padding: 20px 40px;
}
.preview h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.preview p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.page.com/album">
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Record-Album-02.jpg" title="Photo Albums" alt="" />
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>Photo Albums</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="http://www.page.com/storybook">
    <div class="preview">
        <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/RiA/6a5/RiA6a5eoT.jpeg" title="Digital Story Books" alt="" />
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>Digital Story Books</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

How can I line them up so that there is a half an inch of space in between?

Here is a preview of what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/FZ2rZ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
.preview {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}
```

Inline-block for the div containing the image will display the images in a row as you'd like. The margin applies 40px to the right side of the images.

By default images are block elements, meaning they will take up the entire width of the page. Inline elements (like an  or  tag) do not collapse and will be on the same row. [Learn more about display CSS property.](http://devdocs.io/css/display)

*edited to correct margin instead of padding.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid float if you can.  Floating is for a limited scenario.  Usually it is appropriate to use `display:inline-block;`.  That said, when you do, any space you have inbetween tags will also be displayed (you're making it "inline" and spaces are inline, too.)

You can take what you have an add this CSS:

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
}
a:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left:.5in;
}
```

Then, delete the space here

```
</a>

<a href="http://www.page.com/storybook">
```

to get

```
</a><a href="http://www.page.com/storybook">
```

[Here's your modified fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ2rZ/1/)